# What is the best way to ship cards?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I have about 25 cards I want to sell on Star City Games buy list. What would be the best way to ship them? I need them to arrive in the same order I sent them.

Comment: I feel "best" is going to depend a lot on what you're actually shipping; you should probably take a lot more care with a Black Lotus than you would with a few $10 cards.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should I ship cards?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/45165/how-should-i-ship-cards)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Star City Games provides [shipping guidelines/recommendations](https://help.starcitygames.com/approval-instructions).

> Packaging Guidelines
>
> > Following these guidelines will help ensure your collection arrives safely and your Sell List Request or Ship + Sell will be processed efficiently.
> >
> > 1. Remove all cards from binders, top-loaders, and sleeves (standard-style or inner sleeves, including side-loading or sealable).
> > 2. Keep all cards facing the same way, in the same orientation (for example: all facing forward and right-side-up).
> > 3. For Sell List Requests, put the cards in the same order as they are listed on the approved Sell List Request. This will be in the order in which you have entered your cards.
> >
> > Failure to adhere to the above guidelines may result in processing time delays, a penalty of up to 5% off the final total, or our declining of the sale outright.
> >
> > 4. Ensure that all items are packaged safely and securely by packing cards using supplies such as bubble wrap, packing paper, or another flexible material to fill space.
> >
> > Do not use regular envelopes, as these are sorted by machines at the Post Office and can result in damage.
> >
> > Some packaging container suggestions that work well for Magic cards include:
> >
> > Plastic card cases
> > Deck boxes
> > Fat Pack/Bundle boxes
> > Snap cases
> > Rowed card storage boxes
> > Cardboard trading card boxes
> >
> > Plastic bags, rubber bands, or packaging materials with rough surfaces will damage cards. Top-loaders are not recommended due to damaging cards if bent in any way.
> >
> > 5. Send your cards or collection to us. Please use the correct mailing address based on your sale request method.

There will likely be other good answer based on personal experience, but this is a good minimum starting place.